# Web server responding slow while doing data scraping

Tags: css, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to perform a task that requires me to entrance and exit the player info in this page: [https://www.baseball-reference.com/leaders/WAR_bat_career.shtml](https://stackoverflow.com). In this case, I have to get into the webpage of Barry Bonds, who is ranked the first on the standing, scrape the desired data, then move on to Babe Ruth, who trailed only after Bonds by WAR, and so on and so forth.

Through the process, I've encountered two problems:

1. Error(429): Too many requests
2. The speed of retrieving data is getting slower after I violate the error(429)
   I am not sure whether the second point has anything to do with the first one, so any information or assistance will be appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

import requests
import pandas as pd

def counting_WAR(df):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        if type(df.iloc[i]["Age"]) is str:
            age = int(df.iloc[i]["Age"])
            if age <= 30:
                WAR = float(df.iloc[i]["WAR"])
                sum += WAR
            else: return sum

root_page = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/leaders/WAR_bat_career.shtml"
root_soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(root_page), features = 'lxml')
root_df = pd.read_html(requests.get('https://www.baseball-reference.com/leaders/WAR_bat_career.shtml').text.replace('<!--','').replace('-->',''), attrs={'id':'leader_standard_WAR_bat'})[0]

index = 0

for td in root_soup.find_all('td', csk = True):
    for a in td.find_all('a', href = True):
        player_page = ("http://www.baseball-reference.com" + a.get('href'))
        df = pd.read_html(requests.get(player_page).text.replace('<!--','').replace('-->',''), attrs={'id':'batting_value'})[0]
        df[(~df.Lg.isna()) & (df.Lg != 'Lg')]
        war_before_30 = "{:.2f}".format(counting_WAR(df))
        print("Player:", root_df["Player (yrs, age)"][index], "accumulates:", war_before_30, " WAR before 30")
        index += 1
```

How long should I actively halt the process, or I shouldn't? Why is the speed of retrieving data suddenly become so slow? I am a total newbie of the pandas library, so any info that helps me build up the idea of how to use pandas effectively will help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response status code indicates the user
> has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate
> limiting").

The server protects itself from too many requests and slows down, but a Retry-After header might be included to this response indicating how long to wait before making a new request.

This feedback should be respected as a matter of principle and a corresponding term should be calculated in. If official APIs are available, it would be good to switch to them.

However, it could also be a configuration issue, sometimes it could already help to designate a corresponding `user-agent` in the request or to rotate the IP in case of doubt.

Comment: Hi @HedgeHog, thanks for following up my questions after the last one. So I ran this code in my terminal, but the only message I received was error(429) without any retry-after header. Is there anyway to actively get the information?

Comment: *it could already help to designate a corresponding user-agent in the request or to rotate the IP in case of doubt*